# Unexpected token { on import of MDC for web

Tags: javascript

Trying to import Material Design Components into web page just doing copy-paste from the docs and receive an error

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
in the line with the first import

What i'm doing wrong?

```
<script>
import {MDCTopAppBar} from '@material/top-app-bar';
import {MDCDrawer} from "@material/drawer";

const drawer = MDCDrawer.attachTo(document.querySelector('.mdc-drawer'));

const topAppBar = MDCTopAppBar.attachTo(document.getElementById('app-bar'));
topAppBar.setScrollTarget(document.getElementById('main-content'));
topAppBar.listen('MDCTopAppBar:nav', () => {
    drawer.open = !drawer.open;
});
</script>
```

Comment: How are you [transpiling](https://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript-transpilers-what-they-are-why-we-need-them) the code? Probably the problem is with the settings of your transpiler.

Comment: Also, MDC just went through a major version bumb recently, are you sure you're looking at the docs for the version you actually have?

Comment: code is taken from https://material.io/develop/web/components/drawers/